# Atualização de elemento com JQuery com retorno de outro script

Tags: php, jquery

Tenho um `formulário de e-mail simples`, e quando clicar em "Enviar" o "status" aparece ao lado do botão, por exemplo:

`Enquanto envia`, aparece "Enviando..." (isso já está funcionando)

O `problema` é o seguinte:
Meu form está no "index", e a `action do form` está em outro arquivo "email.php".

Como eu faço para o `JQuery` receber o `retorno` do "email.php" e saber se o e-mail foi enviado ou não, para poder atualizar o "status"

No index:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#email').submit(function() {
                $('#emlst').text('Enviando...');
                //if do retorno
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Sem nem conhecermos o código fica difícil porque teremos que advinhar o que foi feito..

Comment: Se eu entendi, você pode enviar o e-mail por ajax, se quiser te mostro o codigo

Comment: @Bsalvo Postei como estou fazendo no index... No script que envia o e-mail é o básico, normal, retornando false ou true.

Comment: @VictorPereira gostaria de ver sim !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esse é um envio de e-mail por ajax/jquery, ve se você consegue entender, é bem simples, esta comentado nas linhas importantes:

```
$(function() {
   $('#email').submit(function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault(); //cancela a troca de página

      var formData = $('#email').serialize(); //Serializa o form em um post

      $('.btn-enviar').attr('disabled','disabled').css('cursor', 'wait'); //desativa o botão para não ficarem clicando
      $('#emlst').text('Enviando...'); //Altera a msg de envio

      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: $('#email').attr('action'), //pega o link de action
         data: formData
      })
      .done(function(response) {
         var result = JSON.parse(response);

         $('#email')[0].reset(); //reseta o formulario
         $('.btn-enviar').removeAttr('disabled','disabled').css('cursor', 'pointer'); //retorna o botão para clicar

         $('#emlst').text('E-mail Enviado'); //Altera a msg caso enviado
      })
      .fail(function(data) {
         $('#emlst').text('Erro');
         $('.btn-enviar').removeAttr('disabled','disabled').css('cursor', 'pointer');
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: Acredito que se você jogar o código que coloquei a cima, já vá funcionar em seu site, só coloca a classe do seu botão de envio no campo do botão.

Comment: Ele fica em `Enviado...` mas acho que é por causa do retorno... o script retorno true ou false conforme o sucesso.

Comment: esqueci de avisar, que no final do seu código php você precisa color um die();

Answer (score 1):

Eu não sei se entendi muito bem, mas se entendi, o seu codigo que faz o envio do email está em outro arquivo, certo? (foi o que eu entendi com o `action do form`).

Se for realmente isso, é simples, vamos simular que você esteja usando `PHP` para o envio do email.

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'SEU ARQUIVO',
   data: $('#form').serialize(),
   dataType: 'json',
   beforeSend: function(){
       $('.msg').text('Enviando...')
   },
   success: function(data){
      $('.msg').text(data.msg)
   }
})
```

Com isso, já estariamos enviado os dados para o formulario, alem de alterar a mensagem, agora vamos ver como ficaria o arquivo `PHP`

```
<?php
   $retorno = array();

   // aqui vai todo o seu codigo de envio de email
   if($mail){
       $retorno['msg'] = 'Email enviado com sucesso';
   }else{
       $retorno['msg'] = 'Erro ao enviar email';
   }

   die(json_encode($retorno));
```

Comment: Vou testar isso Rafael ! Mas me tire uma dúvida, da forma que estou tentando fazer, somente com o AJAX trabalhando no script de envio (email.php), porque teoricamente eu não tenho mesmo como "pegar" o retorno do "email.php" ?

Comment: Exatamente, você precisa retonar resposta, então o indicado, seria ter um arquivo só para isso.

Comment: Muito obrigado Rafael ! Vou tentar o que o Victor mandou, que está mais fácil para eu que sei muito pouco disso entender.

Comment: @RaoniBZ Sem problemas, mas é importante da uma estudada futuramente. Abraços e sucesso.